# WHM Glue records - creating nameservers for non master account?

Tags: domains, dns, whm

This question concerns Glue Records. I have a reseller account with WHM included which has its own nameservers (this is the master domain for my account). I also have another domain for which I want to create nameservers for in WHM which is unrelated to this master account.

I have set these new nameservers up in the zone file, but I'm getting the parent/child mismatch obviously. So my question is, is there anything I can do in the master domain zone file to advise the nameservers for this new domain (they have the same IP address). Or do I have to pass this to the support team to do it at the registrar?

I cannot seem to find a definitive answer. There's lots of copied and pasted text referring to authoritative this and that, but it doesn't really explain how I achieve what I want in this instance, due to being a reseller.

Answer (score 1):

It may depend on your registrar, but in my case, I set up what is called 'child name nameservers' in one registrar and 'registry hosts' in another, but they both do the same thing, that is where you create something like ns1.yourdomain.com, ns2.yourdomain.com as nameserver values.

Then in WHM go to Home »Server Configuration »Basic cPanel & WHM Setup add name servers.

Comment: thanks for your input, i have updated the WHM setup nameservers, but do not have access to those setting with my Registrar, so i have sent a support ticket. Hopefully i will get a definitive answer.